# DC-DC + LDO in series

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ldo

Typically the question is: after having selected all the components in a schematic minus the Power Management systems, we then define which voltage and current each block will use, then we need to convert the power source into power rail to power each block. This is mostly done with LDO and DC-DC converter.

I have difficulties to understand in which situations we are using a DC-DC converter in series with a LDO vs (LDO alone or DC-DC alone).

Does anyone can enlight me to understand how we build the block of power management system in a block diagram or a schematic ?

Comment: Why not just set the DC-DC converter output to the voltage you require and forget about the series regulator?

Comment: A good app note on the topic from TI: SNVA871 (April 2019)
Output Noise Filtering for DC/DC Power Modules (Jimmy Hua). An LDO following a switching converter is a simple approach to reduce noise, if you need to reduce noise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switching converters are generally more efficient than linear regulators, although there are circumstances where an LDO can be comparable or even more efficient.
2. Linear regulators can't produce Vout > Vin, only a switching regulator can do that.
3. Switching regulators inherently produce a certain amount of switching ripple at their outputs. So linear regulators are generally less noisy than switching regulators.
4. A combination of switching regulator with an LDO post-regulator is often used to achieve both decent efficiency and low noise. But efficiency is not as good as a switching regulator alone, and there is a cost in parts and board area.

Comment: I know already the advantages and drawback of LDO and DC-DC converter alone. The question is how do we choose LDO/DC-DC alone versus LDO+DC-DC in series. How to mitigate this choice ? working with an example woudl be welcome. If you can supply with methodology you use to make those choice, it would be also very interesting

Comment: @chris, I answered that in paragraph 4.

Comment: Hi, can you illustrate with some data (voltage / current) in which case (based on data calculation or datasheet consideration), you would would use a series ?

Comment: "how do we choose" - as always, based on the requirements!

Comment: @chris, you choose the switcher+LDO combination when it's the lowest cost (by the metrics of your project) way to achieve your requirements for efficiency and noise. It's as simple as that. There's so much variety in all of these factors (cost metrics, noise requirements, efficiency requirements) that there is no "typical" case to illustrate with an example.

Comment: In this case tomorrow I will edit this post to submit a circuit and will ask which PMS I should use in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have difficulties to understand in which situations we are using a
>   DC-DC converter in series with a LDO vs (LDO alone or DC-DC alone).

There are a number of things to consider:

1) Just how much power is needed?

2) How important is efficiency?

3) How important is low noise?

4) How important is power density?

Until you answer those questions, there is no way to address your concern. In other words, the question cannot be answered as a general matter.

But first, keep in mind that not all linear regulators are LDO (low drop out), but LDO regulators are always linear, so your question as stated is incomplete.

If high efficiency or high power density is required, a switching supply (DC-DC converter) is the solution of choice. Note that this requires that the other issues do not come into play.

If noise is critical and the power required is not great, a purely linear (which does not necessarily imply LDO) regulator is chosen. If this approach produces too much power loss, it's time to get creative. Note, for example, that if a 24 volt system needs a clean 5 volts at 10 mA, a purely linear regulator will operate at about 20% efficiency - but it will only waste 0.2 watts. A very small linear regulator should be able to handle this, and the wasted power is unlikely to be a problem, while even the smallest DC-DC circuit will almost certainly be larger (especially once the output filters are included), and will not save a great deal of power. Unless, of course, the system is a long-endurance, battery-powered system where efficiency is critical.

If noise is important, and the power losses involved in a purely linear solution are too great (power density comes into play) then a DC-DC converter followed by a linear regulator can be considered. Note that switching noise can always be filtered out - it's just that the resources (such as board space) required to do so may be unacceptable.

To sum it up, as with all engineering such choices are critically dependent on the specific system requirements. Numbers always matter.